# AWS S3, get list of objects per suffix/month

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is it possible to calculate the number of new objects that arrived to our S3 bucket per suffix/month based on Last Modified date?
Assuming this is the content of our bucket:

```
Name            Last modified
pic01.jpg       2022-01-20
pic02.jpg       2022-01-22
doc01.pdf       2022-01-23
doc02.pdf       2022-01-25
doc03.pdf       2022-01-28
pic11.jpg       2022-02-01
pic12.jpg       2022-02-05
pic13.jpg       2022-02-10
doc11.pdf       2022-02-15
```

Desirable outbut:

```
Suffix      Month       Count
jpg         2022-01     2
pdf         2022-01     3
jpg         2022-02     3
pdf         2022-02     1
```

Comment: Look at [S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/storage-inventory.html).

Comment: Yes. You can use an AWS SDK in your favourite programming language. What language do you wish to use?

Comment: Preferably Python @JohnRotenstein

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounded like an interesting challenge, so I wrote this:

```py
import boto3

suffixes = {}

BUCKET = 'BUCKETNAME'

s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')

for object in s3_resource.Bucket(BUCKET).objects.all():
    key = object.key
    month = object.last_modified.strftime("%Y-%m")
    if '.' in key:
        suffix = key[key.rfind('.') + 1:]
        suffixes[(month, suffix)] = suffixes.get((month, suffix), 0) + 1

for key, value in sorted(suffixes.items()):
    print(key[1], key[0], value)
```

It will:

- Loop through all objects in the bucket
- If the Key contains a period, it will store the month and suffix in a dictionary
- It then sorts the dictionary and prints the contents

The output is:

```
jpg 2014-03 1
yaml 2021-02 1
overlay 2021-03 1
txt 2021-06 1
py 2021-07 1
txt 2021-09 1
py 2021-10 1
jpg 2022-03 2
```